# UINavigationBar Rounded Two Corners

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, rounded-corners

I want to round the top right and top left of the UINavigationBar.

I know that there are functions for changing the views corner radius, but is it possible to do something similar to the standard UINavigationBar?

If you don't know what I'm talking about, check out this:
 
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: it's possible to change view corner radiuss, but it will affect all corners!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way is to override drawRect in UINavigationBar and use a custom image.

Comment: -drawRect: doesn't get called in iOS 5 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575821/custom-nav-bar-styling-ios/6389991#6389991

Comment: Thanks for updating this.  I should hope everyone nowadays is informed of the UIAppearance protocol though.

Answer (score 44):

the following code works for me (tested on iOS5).
The following code rounds the top left/right corners of the main navigation bar. Additionally, it adds a shadow to it:

```
CALayer *capa = [self.navigationController navigationBar].layer;
[capa setShadowColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[capa setShadowOpacity:0.85f];
[capa setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.5f)];
[capa setShadowRadius:2.0f];  
[capa setShouldRasterize:YES];


//Round
CGRect bounds = capa.bounds;
bounds.size.height += 10.0f;    //I'm reserving enough room for the shadow
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:bounds 
                                               byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight)
                                                     cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

[capa addSublayer:maskLayer];
capa.mask = maskLayer;
```

Comment: @Joze it works like a charm, but my UIButton back stop working...Why?

Comment: Hi Juan. Maybe the button.frame.origin.y is being masked. Try to change the y coordinate (maybe +2 pixels) and try it. Maybe that's the problem

Comment: Fantastic answer! This really makes the navigation bar look great. A quick issue that I ran into for others reading:  If you get a mach-o linker error, you have to link the quartzcore library in your project settings. Thanks again @Joze!

Comment: Like @jonstaff said, link to the quartzcore.framework file in your project settings, but also put: #import <Quartz/Quartz.h> in the .m file wherever you're trying to use this code.

Comment: i wonder why its not working with UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful. Maybe you could also do some kind of masking with CoreAnim/Image? I'm not very knowledgeable about the Core* family...

http://foobarpig.com/iphone/uinavigationbar-with-solid-color-or-image-background.html