# How can I set image in background of navigation bar in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ipad

How we set image in navigation bar in iPhone?

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"banner.png"]];`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom nav bar styling - iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575821/custom-nav-bar-styling-ios)

Answer (score 1):

This won't work in iOS 5 correctly. See this answer for how to implement this in a way that works in iOS5 and previous versions. [Custom nav bar styling - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575821/custom-nav-bar-styling-ios/6389991#6389991)

This is a much better way to do things and ensures your app will work in multiple versions of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
```

This puts the image in your navigation bar title.