# Flat navigation bar

Tags: iphone, xcode

How would I go about creating a navigation bar which looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbaCz.png

It's more flat than the default bar, and the dropshadow inside the title also seems different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to create some custom resources and use them either with a `-drawRect:` override, or if you are okay targeting only iOS 5, `UIAppearance`.

These links should help.

1. [Create A Custom UINavigationBar Style](http://devinsheaven.com/create-a-custom-uinavigationbar-style/)
2. [Custom nav bar styling - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575821/custom-nav-bar-styling-ios)

Edit: also for the title text, you'll want to add a custom `UILabel` setup how you like as the titleView of the navigation controller. Or for iOS 5 you can use the `titleTextAttributes` on `UINavigationBar`.