# How to customize UINavigationBar in IOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationbar, customization

In IOS5, I do not yet know how to customize UINavigationBar.

My code is like this:

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5f alpha:1.0]];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor blackColor],UITextAttributeTextColor 
,[UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor 
,[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset
,[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20.0],UITextAttributeFont 
, nil]];


    // Customize UIBarButtonItems
 UIImage *gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"title__bg.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];       

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor
,[UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor 
,[NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset
,[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0],UITextAttributeFont
, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // Customize back button items differently
    UIImage *buttonBack30 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bn_back"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 5)];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonBack30 forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This pic is UINavigationViewController used in PopoverView.
[image]

This pic is UINavigationViewController opened by Modal.
[image]

As you see, I set background-image, nevertheless NavigationBar's border is different.

Is this a problem about PopoverView?

I do not know What I'd missed.

Please tell me your advice. Thanks!!! and Happy new year!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575821/custom-nav-bar-styling-ios/6389991#6389991

Answer (score 1):

Goto AppDelegate.m and paste the code under

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Set the status bar to black color.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque 
                                            animated:NO];
```

Change @"menubar.png" to the file name of your image.

```
 UIImage *navBar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menubar.png"];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBar 
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score -4):

Have a look at this: [UINavigationBar Apple developer reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-SW16)