# clear background image in navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios4

I have the following code in viewWillAppear in my view controller.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imageView];
}
```

How do I clear the navigation bar background image that is already there before adding a new nav bar image as in the code above?

Also, how can I set a different navigation bar background image for each different controller the most efficient way possible? thanks!

Comment: use UIAppearance for setting different navbar styles.

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736171/how-to-customize-uinavigationbar-in-ios5?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your viewWillAppear method, use the following call to set the background image of the navigation bar.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If your app supports landscape as well, you'll also need to set the background image for the landscape navigation bar with a different height:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_landscape.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

Comment: I have a question - how do we prevent the back button from being animated when people click back? Right now the back button slides to the center when clicked. How can we stop that?

Comment: in viewWillDisappear method, set the back button to nil: self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil