# How to design custom navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have searched lots for how to design navigation like given in the image.

[image]
I have created category for `UINavigationBar` like given in the following solution
[Custom nav bar styling - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5575821/custom-nav-bar-styling-ios)

Able to increase the size of `NavigationBar` using below code.

```
CGFloat navBarHeight = 84.0f;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, navBarHeight);
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:frame];
```

But all content like (left button, right button, title) moves to bottom of bar.

When attach segment control to titleView like below

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.segmentedControl;
```

All views( left button, title, right button) as liner.

I want `segment control` bottom of the navigation bar as shown in the image.

Comment: Do you want it same through-out your app ?

Comment: Hi @Aman this want for one viewController.

Comment: then add it simply to your viewController

Answer (score 1):

@Shankar Shinde why are you adding segment controller as navigation title view you can add below the navigation bar using storyboard: check below screen shot

[image]

I think you need to hide the navigation bar using following code and create view like attached screenshot let me know it's help you or not ?

```
 [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```

[image]

Comment: This is our product design decision. I have done same as you posted. if you any idea Please help.

Comment: I have done through coding. On view added all subviews (left,right, and segment control). That view as part of viewController like  `[self.view addSubview:...]`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out sample:

https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/WoodUINavigation

It may help you :)

Comment: hey Gaurav , thank you for reference, This is not what I am looking :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Prompt** provided for navigationItem
First give prompt to your navigationItem

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = @"";
```

Create a segmentcontroll

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(35, 200, 250, 50);
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:segmentedControl];
```