# Way to make corners square in ViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've built out a demo app and am wondering if there is any way to now change this app to have square corners in the top menu bar of the app? I've seen other apps that have this and wondering if someone could point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this. Thanks!

```
Before:
```

[image]

```
After:
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [UINavigationBar Rounded Two Corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235375/uinavigationbar-rounded-two-corners). My solution didn't work, try this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 6.0 or later, if you set the status bar style to `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque`, you get rounded corners.  If you set the status bar style to `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` or `UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent`, you get square corners.

[image: status bar styles]

Comment: This solved it...Thanks! Really appreciate it! [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:NO];